# Regular expressions: grab part of string

Tags: javascript, regex

So I got the following input inside my textarea element:

> `<quote>hey</quote>`
>
> `what's up?`

I want to separate the text between the `<quote>` and `</quote>` ( so the result would be 'hey' and nothing else in this case.

I tried with .replace and the following regular expression, but it did not achieve the right result and I can't see why:

`quoteContent = value.replace(/<quote>|<\/quote>.*/gi, '');` **(the result is `'hey what's up'`it doesn't remove the last part, in this case `'what's up'`, it only removes the quote marks)**

**Does someone know how to solve this?**

Comment: `/(?<=<quote>).*?(?=<\/quote>)/.exec(yourString)`

Comment: in ESNext, with the [`s` mode](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-dotall-flag). Before that, use `[\s\S]` or similar to match everything.

Comment: obligatory https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try using the `match` method:

`quoteContent = value.match(/<quote>(.+)<\/quote>/)[1];`

Comment: you may need the non-greedy modifier: `(.*?)`

Comment: Yes, good point.  And also probably want to make sure the match is successful before trying to access it.  Otherwise it will throw an error.

Answer (score 3):

Even if it's only a small html snippet, [don't use regex to do any html parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not). Instead, take the value, use DOM methods and extract the text from an element. A bit more code, but the better and safer way to do that:

```js
const el = document.getElementById('foo');
const tmp = document.createElement('template');
tmp.innerHTML = el.value;
console.log(tmp.content.querySelector('quote').innerText);
```

```html
<textarea id="foo">
<quote>hey</quote>

what's up?
</textarea>
```

Comment: I see, but here it is more some random string I made to create a forum reply instead of an actual element.

Comment: You're absolutely free to use an regex approach for your html parsing. Just don't wonder if your code breaks later; that's why I posted the correct approach @tilly. Changing the selector in getElementsByTagName is even much easier and more dynamic than the regex selector

Comment: And don't use `.innerHTML` on anything other than a `<template>` element if you don't trust the string.  `<img onerror=alert(1) src=bogus>` will run javascript even if the node is not attached to the document root.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to avoid parsing HTML using regular expressions.

```
<quote><!-- parsing HTML is hard when </quote> can appear in a comment -->hey</quote>
```

You can just use the DOM to do it for you.

```
// Parse your fragment
let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(
    '<quote>hey</quote>\nWhat\'s up?', 'text/html')
// Use DOM lookup to find a <quote> element and get its
// text content.
let { textContent } = doc.getElementsByTagName('quote')[0]
// We get plain text and don't need to worry about "&lt;"s
textContent === 'hey'
```

Answer (score -1):

The dot `.` will not match new lines.

Try this:

```
//(.|\n)* will match anything OR a line break
quoteContent = value.replace(/<quote>|<\/quote>(.|\n)*/gi, '');
```

Comment: Yes! That was it. Thanks everyone for helping

Comment: Besides recommending parsing HTML with regular expressions, `.|\n` will not match `[\r\u2028\u2029]`.

Comment: **Never** use `(.|\n)*` unless you are using a Lucene regex engine. It is a performance killer.